# XNA Vector3 into Vector3D

Tags: c#, xna, audio

I'm using the IrrKlang sound library to create 3D sounds in a game. Problem is the listener set is looking for a Vector3D position, but the variables I have are in Vector3. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply convert your Vector3 to a Vector3D, since Vector3D is simply a struct with X, Y, Z member variables to represent the x, y, z components a function like this should work fine:

```
public static Vector3D ToVector3D(Vector3 input)
{
   return new Vector3D( (float)input.X, (float)input.Y, (float)input.Z );
}
```

Perhaps you could implement it as an extension to Vector3 (i.e. Vector3.ToVector3D()), but at any rate converting your Vector3 to Vector3D is very trivial and the above code should help :)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing. :D